# cannot unblock wifi hard block with anything on Lenovo x230t

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I have tried all solutions found here or on ubuntuforums.com, but no luck whatsoever.

It all started very randomly: I had my mother's nokia lumia connect via usb to my lenovo x230t, I disconnected it (without safely removing it first - ouch) and, when I unplugged the cable, I got the network disconnection alert on the top right corner of the screen and the wifi got hardware blocked.

My rfkill list is

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

After this moment it the "Enable wifi" option has always been greyed out. I've tried :

- the FN+key button, but no message whatsoever (actually looks like that command is not recognised)
- `sudo rfkill unblock 1` and `2`, but no effect whatsoever
- `sudo rfkill unblock all`, but nothing
- blocking first, and this changes the `no` to `yes`, but then redoing `sudo rfkill unblock 1`changes only the `Soft blocked`, leaving the `Hard blocked` to `no`
- `echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf` and nothing even here
- tried in the BIOS, but in my version there's no "Wireless Radio LAN" option

Another piece of information: every time I open System settings -> Network, the **Airplane mode** is on
This has never happened before, so the cause is surely linked to the unplugging the smartphone. Maybe it hit on a system bug. Now the question is: how do I fix it?

I beg some expert for help, as this is the laptop I use for work and not being able to connect wirelessly is creating quite some problems.
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide `dmesg` output?

Comment: Does your PC has an hardware switch(eg. Fn+wireless, trigger,...). If so, try to toggle it (there won't be any output) and check `rfkill` status again

Comment: Yes, there's the Fn key but pressing it with the wireless button has no effect whatsoever, not even a symbol or communication on the screen. nothing, dead. I'm posting the output of dmesg on an answer as it's too long for a comment

Comment: Use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) to post dmesg output

Comment: thanks, great idea! here's the URL (hope this is the right way) http://pastebin.com/MuHKqZ0F

Comment: Any news? has anyone any idea on how to solve this? Thx

Comment: Try to blacklist `thinkpad_acpi` module

Comment: I tried `echo blacklist thinkpad_acpi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf`, rebooted the laptop but no luck. the wifi is still blocked

Comment: I guess that the only solution left is to restore from an old backup. Please notify the problem to the OS programmers. Thanks anyway for the support

Answer (score 1):

if you have the realtek NIC then you should try this [tape trick to mask a pin](https://youtu.be/yzAKcmlaH1M) only after the problem still persists after trying the other solutions such as unblock command. In my laptop the same problem had occurred and I myself applied the trick and since then my WiFi works like charm.